# how do i move selected elements from one Jlist to another Jlist in a different Class

Tags: java, swing, jlist

i have created a menu where i got 4 classes. i created a Jlist for each course meal which contains different elements. How do i know get these selected items to display in another Jlist in a different Class which also contains a Jlist.

Comment: What do you mean a different class?

Comment: Are you setting the second, updated dlm to your second `JList`?

Comment: Because when you say `dessertList = new JList(dlm);` you are binding the dlm to the `JList` but you are then calling `.setModel(dlm)` on the same `JList`

Comment: @Jonah the Jlist works fine now. i done the second (dlm2) however the code which you suggested :dessertList.getSelectedValuesList().forEach(dlm2::addElement); the "forEach(dlm2::addElement);" is highlighted as red suggesting that the line of code is wrong

Comment: Take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: the new code  for(String item : list1.getSelectedValuesList())  the list1.getSelectedValuesList()) is shown as red again suggesting it is not working

Comment: @Jonah  i manage to fix it.Thank you. However when i run the code it gives me this error even doe all my code is right atm. ill update it on my post

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [Default List Models](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html)

You can create a DLM and share it's contents between other DLM's. You could start to go about doing it by adding something like this in your first class

```
DefaultListModel dlm = new DefaultListModel();
JList list1 = new JList(dlm);
```

You could then add the default elements to the DLM and create a function in your other class that assigns that DLM to your other `JList`

```
public static void setDLM(DefaultListModel dlm)
{
    list2.setModel(dlm);
}
```

You should then static import the `setDLM()` method, and execute the following in your buttons `ActionListener`

```
DefaultListModel<String> dlm2 = new DefaultListModel<>();

for(String item : list1.getSelectedValuesList())
{
   dlm2.addElement(item);
}

setDLM(dlm2);
```

Comment: Or use `addElement(E)` which will do the same thing as `add(int, E)`, but with less code (and without overriding what was at `i`)

Comment: @MadProgrammer, Yes, My original solution was to rewrite the original dlm with the selected values but decided having 2 dlms was better

Comment: Yes, you need two models (and two `JList`s), but you still need to address how to remove the original values from the first list ;)

Comment: @Jonah right i followed what you said but once i added my elements to my DefaultListModel it doesnt show my elements in my Jlist

Comment: Could you post your code that you have tried as an edit to your question?

Comment: @Jonah i have added my Jlist item which didnt display